# Calling Lua Function from C: Minimal example results in LUA_ERRRUN

Tags: c, lua, lua-api, lua-5.2

I want to call an external lua_5.2 function from C, so I made a minimal example to try it out.

The minimal testfile:

```lua
--- filename: play.lua
function hello()
    print("Hello World!\n")
end
```

Trying to call this function from C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"


int
main(void) {
    lua_State *L;
    int status;
    int result;

    L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    status = luaL_loadfile(L, "play.lua");
    if (status != LUA_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not load 'play.lua'!");
        exit(1);
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "hello");
    if (lua_isfunction(L, -1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Not a function!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    result = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (result!= LUA_OK) {
        fprintf(sterr, "Error running lua: %i\n", result);
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "lua ran fine\n");
    lua_pop(L, lua_gettop(L));

    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

Calling that executable results however in LUA_ERRUN (2)

```
Error running lua: 2
```

I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong here, and the documentation is a little bit opaque to me -- according to the [5.2 reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall) I am using `pcall` correctly (function with zero args and zero return vals), and I apparently grabbed the function from the stack correctly (otherwise they earlier error would have shown).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try `luaL_dofile` instead of `luaL_loadfile`. which only loads but does not run a script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/32873597/107090

Comment: The actual error message gets pushed to the stack doesn't it. It should give you more of an idea of what went wrong.

Comment: lhf: I dont want to immediatly call that function, they are just close together for the sake of example. As I can tell from the manual (referenced in that answer you linked), `dofile` is equivalent to `define func(); call func()` which I don't want

Comment: also shouldn't this be negated `if (lua_isfunction(L, -1))`

Comment: Ahhhhhh of course, yes. No wonder if wont work then. I'll look at that, and then will see in the docs how to poke around the stack for the error. thanks!

Comment: I think they are probably right about the dofile, as in native lua I had to execute the function returned from load, before being able to execute the hello function. `load(playLuaStr)(); hello();`, so probably your `lua_getglobal` isn't working as `hello` doesn't exist.

Comment: A small problem: `fprintf(sterr, "Error running lua: %i\n", result);` - this example does not compile (`sterr`). Please ensure that you are copying your [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) precisely - avoid transcribing by hand, when possible, and instead copy and paste complete examples immediately after checking their validity. It may seem minor, but typos like this can create doubt as to the correctness of *other* sections of the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the return value of [`lua_pcall`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_pcall) is *not* [`LUA_OK`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-LUA_OK), an error message will have been pushed onto the top of the stack.

This value can be manipulated with functions like `lua_tostring` for use in C.

```
result = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);

if (result != LUA_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error running lua: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
    exit(1);
}
```

(*You can also propagate the error with `lua_error(L)`, but that may defeat the purpose of the protected call.*)

Doing this reveals the error

```
Error running lua: attempt to call a nil value
```

which means `lua_getglobal(L, "hello");` pushed *nil* onto the stack.

(*Note that we only get this far because `if (lua_isfunction(L, -1))` is the inverse condition to check for.*)

The value of the global variable `hello` is *nil* because the [*chunk*](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3.2) containing its definition was never executed. That is, `luaL_loadfile` (ultimately [`lua_load`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_load)) only *loads* chunks, it does not execute them.

After loading a chunk, you may execute it like any other function (`lua_call`, etc.).

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

int
main(void) {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();

    luaL_openlibs(L);

    int status;
    int result;

    status = luaL_loadfile(L, "play.lua"); /* load the chunk */
    if (status != LUA_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not load 'play.lua': %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
    }

    result = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0); /* execute the chunk */
    if (result != LUA_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error running lua: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
    }

    lua_getglobal(L, "hello");
    if (!lua_isfunction(L, -1)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Not a function!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    result = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (result != LUA_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error running lua: %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        exit(1);
    }

    puts("lua ran fine");
    lua_close(L);
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!

lua ran fine
```

---

Note that [`luaL_dofile`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_dofile) is a macro defined as

```
(luaL_loadfile(L, filename) || lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0))
```

and is a convenient way to load and execute a chunk.